# Python gprc AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'message_types_by_name'

Tags: grpc-python

I just want to complete a simple demo, but I got this error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/grpc/biliService.py", line 10, in <module>
    import hello_bilibili_pb2 as pb2
  File "E:\grpc\hello_bilibili_pb2.py", line 21, in <module>
    _HELLODEWEIREQ = DESCRIPTOR.message_types_by_name['HelloDeweiReq']
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'message_types_by_name'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grpcio==1.30.0
grpcio-tools==1.30.0
```

The latest `grpcio` version `1.44.0` generate incompatible *pb2* files,  so I've seen the same question, I downgrade `grpcio 1.30.0`， and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I wasn't able to run this inside docker for these versions for some reason 