# Python Bigquery import fails on Windows

Tags: python, windows, google-bigquery

I'm trying to use `from google.cloud import bigquery` in my Python script, but it fails with the following error:

```
Script failed to evaluate():

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'message_types_by_name'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Python Script", line 4, in <module>
    from google.cloud import bigquery
  File "__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from google.cloud.bigquery.client import Client
  File "client.py", line 60, in <module>
    import google.api_core.exceptions as core_exceptions
  File "exceptions.py", line 29, in <module>
    from google.rpc import error_details_pb2
  File "error_details_pb2.py", line 39, in <module>
    _ERRORINFO = DESCRIPTOR.message_types_by_name["ErrorInfo"]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'message_types_by_name'
```

I'm using Python 3.8.1 (default, Jan 24 2020, 17:35:53) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] and I used the following command to install the dependencies:
`"...\python\python38\python" -m pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade --target="...\some\directory" google-cloud-storage google-cloud-bigquery[pandas]`. I also tried the previous version `google-cloud-bigquery[pandas]==3.11.4` and adding `protobuf` as dependency, which both did not resolve the issue.

For example `from google.oauth2 import service_account` works just fine.

Does anyone have an idea on how I could fix the problem?

Edit: `pip freeze --path ...\some\directory` gives the following output:

```
cachetools==5.3.1
certifi==2023.7.22
charset-normalizer==3.3.0
db-dtypes==1.1.1
google-api-core==2.12.0
google-auth==2.23.3
google-cloud-bigquery==3.11.4
google-cloud-core==2.3.3
google-cloud-storage==2.11.0
google-crc32c==1.5.0
google-resumable-media==2.6.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.60.0
grpcio==1.59.0
idna==3.4
numpy==1.24.4
packaging==23.2
pandas==2.0.3
proto-plus==1.22.3
protobuf==4.24.4
pyarrow==13.0.0
pyasn1==0.5.0
pyasn1-modules==0.3.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2023.3.post1
requests==2.31.0
rsa==4.9
six==1.16.0
tzdata==2023.3
urllib3==2.0.6
```

Comment: Can you also update the question with the result of `pip freeze`?

Comment: What is your `protobuf` version.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM Yes sure, I added the pip freeze output in the end

Comment: try to downgrade grpcio : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71906577/python-gprc-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-message-types-by

Comment: Downgrading grpcio to 1.30.0 sadly did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you try installing latest BQ version ```pip install google-cloud-bigquery==3.12.0``` to your environment?

Comment: @NestorCenizaJr Thanks a lot, installing version 3.12.0. fixed the issue after I had uninstalled all other versions from the environment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comment for better visibility for the community, It appears some libraries is conflicting with the BQ version installed in the environment: recommended to install `pip install google-cloud-bigquery==3.12.0`  and it seems to fixed the issue.

> installing version 3.12.0. fixed the issue after I had uninstalled all other versions from the environment